# Get Parameters along with controller and action name from endpoint

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a HttpGet endpoint that takes in an `id`. I have figured out how to get the controller and action names but I am also wanting to get the parameters used in the endpoint because I want to be able to distinguish them from a normal default GET.

Here is the endpoint and example of what I am wanting:

```
// GET: api/PatientSearch/5
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    _customLogger.LogInfoEvent(this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString());

    return "value";
}
```

This currently works and logs the action as 'Get' But id' like it to log as `'Get {id}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// GET: api/PatientSearch/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        var parameters = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
        var paramNames = String.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.Name)); // myString, myInt


        return this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"] + "{"+ paramNames + "}";
    }
```

Screenshots of test result:
**public string Get(int id)**

[image]

**public string Get(int id, string str)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
```

or

```
var q = id;
```